# Can InDesign CS5 do automatic pagination while import XML data?

Tags: xml, import, flash-cs5, adobe-indesign

I have googled a lot about pagination of importing XML data into InDesign CS5, but problems are still unsolved.

Giving a page with four product elements, if I have a XML file with eight products tag,  I can successfully import it, but only one page with four products will be shown, the left four are gone!

How do I make InDesign CS5 automatic do pagination for my XML import?
thanks a lot.

Comment: An alternative is [Importing XML into InDesign](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16440964/287948).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the book A Designer's Guide to Adobe InDesign and XML. It can explain much of your situation.

But basically, you only need to set up one item on the page and design the layout to flow from position to position using linked frames or paragraph styles. When you import, you select the "Clone" option from the XML import options dialog. This is called the "Flow" method.

If you want completely different layouts for each item, then you have to make one layout for each item you are importing. In the book this is called the "Frame" method. But if you set up four items in your template, InDesign will only import 4.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple: NO! It doesn't support this function.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. I just developed an ad-hoc application at work for this purpose in inDesign CS4. inDesign needs for each element a different xml file. You can import all files at once, but you need a root tag that contains all the elements.