# Importing XML into InDesign

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I am trying to create a template for XML data using InDesign. Basic Structure is:

```
<page>
<section1>
<product><title></title></product>
<product><title></title></product>
...
</section1>
<section2>
....
```

Each section has a variable number of products. Each template will be created with the correct number of sections (although repeating sections with child products would also work).

Is this scenario supported using the Import XML functionality? Can anyone point to a tutorial showing how to set this up?

I have tried some examples, but cannot get InDesign to even repeat the products after adding placeholders and re-importing the file as all tutorials suggest..

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.indesignusergroup.com/chapters/brisbane/files/643/Brisbane_Handout.pdf) article, it might get you going along the lines you need to. It provides a good description of importing XML into InDesign.

Comment: I can only think of maybe creating a minimal IDML from the XML and opening in InDesign, but I guess you'd want something else. I'd jump into the picture if at all your requirements change! ;)

Comment: See also [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9518123/287948).

Answer (score 2):

### A solution by batch processing (a lot of articles)

... The only way that I can use today (2013) is this (semi-automatic) procedure:

1. [*manual, prepare*] **Check** my InDesign "template" file, that will be used as "importer": ***styles* with *legible names*** must by defined. They are all visible (listed) in a HTML+CSS exporting.
2. [*manual, prepare*] **Adapt a XSLT** to convert convert your XML files to XHTML ones, expressing all relevant styles with the attribute *class* and consistent (with item 1) class *names*;
3. [*automatic, batch processing*] **Convert** automatically all XML to XHTML **by the XSLT**;
4. [*automatic, batch processing*] **Convert** automatically all XHTML files to DOC, using [Python OpenDocument Converter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter).
5. [*InDesign assisted, final processing*] **Import each DOC** from a "template" (item 1) file clone at InDesign. The *classes* (item 2) will be automatically transformed by InDesign styles.

This procedure is better than IDML because **use directaly the XHTML as content source for InDesign**. It is not perfect for all applications, but avoids use of non-standard conversion by *IDML*, **avoid to learn IDML, avoid IDML limitations**,  and avoids risks of IDML bugs... So, I think is faster than try and try IDML procedures.

---

Another procedure — **better**, because it allows to express things like footnotes —  is to prepare a direct convertion from XML to MS-Word, by a XSLT that transforms XML into [DOCX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) or [RFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)... Do you have a link or clue for this kind of procedure?

---

MANIFEST

Adobe products **are "closed"** for universal standards (!) importation, like to import [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/).

**How to PROTEST against Adobe?!**

The biggest problem arises when we have many files...

Answer (score 2):

Once you've converted your XML to HTML or DocBook XML, you can use Pandoc to get it into InDesign.

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) has lots of importers (for example from HTML or DocBook XML) and can now export to Adobe InCopy's ICML format. The resulting file can then be placed in InDesign like any other external dependency.

```
pandoc --standalone -t ICML -o output.icml input.html
```